# How to make a reusable UILabel and UITextField programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uilabel

I want to make a reusable UILabel and UITextField so it will not be repeated, how I can do that? this is my code

```
let nameLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Name"
    label.textColor = .white
    return label
}()

let nameTextField: UITextField = {
    let tv = UITextField()
    tv.placeholder = "Name"
    tv.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6078431373, green: 0.6078431373, blue: 0.6078431373, alpha: 1)
    return tv
}()

let emailLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Email"
    label.textColor = .white
    return label
}()

let emailTextField: UITextField = {
    let tv = UITextField()
    tv.placeholder = "Email"
    tv.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6078431373, green: 0.6078431373, blue: 0.6078431373, alpha: 1)
    return tv
}()
```

Comment: Subclass them, or wrap them into a custom control.

Comment: Or use a kind of factory method to generate them with whatever (color, text) you need.

Answer (score 1):

Use computed property , it'll return a new instance every access

```
var emailLabel: UILabel  {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Default"
    label.textColor = .green
    view.addSubview(label)
    return label
}
```

---

```
let em1 = emailLabel 
em1.text = "dshjsdhdshdhdshjdsh" 
em1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)


let em2 = emailLabel 
em2.text = "dshjsdhdshdhdshjdsh"
em2.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100)
```

Comment: UILabel is a class and class is reference type. That means em1 & em2 have the same ref that have emailLabel.

Comment: @dahiya_boy you can try it and see , second access of `emailLabel` returns a new instance

Comment: OH you creating new instance in emailLabel. My mistake.

Comment: But this seems like a weird use of computed property yes? Rather use a function to make it look more readable?

Comment: @Tj3n i intentionally answer this to highlight the difference between it and the op code , off course functions and subclass are another alternatives also